# Sage Pay "Server Integration" For BigCommerce To Accept European Payment Types Such As Giropay and Sofort

Tags: integration, payment, bigcommerce, opayo

I have been asked by BigCommerce Support team to fill out a question to here for some help regarding Sage Pay integrations for BigCommerce.

Currently, BigCommerce offer "Sage Pay/Protx VSP Direct" & "Sage Pay/Protx VSP Form (Hosted)" payment options.

For us to be able to accept European payment types such as Giropay, Sofort, EPS & iDeal - We need to have the "Sage Pay Server Integration" payment option available.

Information on these can be found on the following links:

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/38/protocolv3

The page above lists the 3 options available. BigCommerce currently have 2 of these set up, however we require the third option.

Please see this link for that option in detail:

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/server-integration-documents

On this page there is also a link to PDF guide that we have been sent by Sage Pay to explain this option.

"Local European payments
Accept giropay and sofort payments for customers based in Germany, Austria and The Netherlands.
PDF document - Local European payments instructions"

Is it possible to add the third Sage Pay integration to the BigCommerce platform for us to be able to accept European payment types such as Giropay, Sofort, EPS & iDeal?

Thank you in advance for any help and assistance you may be able to offer!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My apologies, I should have emphasised this section a little more clearly:

"For us to be able to accept European payment types such as Giropay, Sofort, EPS & iDeal - We need to have the "Sage Pay Server Integration" payment option available."

Basically, BigCommerce does not currently have the third Sage Pay Option of "Sage Pay Server Integration"

We need this option to be able to accept European payment types.

Is it possible to add this Sage Pay Integration to the BigCommerce platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the European payment types with the Form integration (undocumented feature), which I believe BigCommerce supports.

eg: (this will probably expire, but you get the idea)

https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp?VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=thewinningteam&Crypt=@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

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Before posting this question, I had spoken with Sage Pay and they informed us this would not be possible using Form or Hosted integrations and would only work with the Server Integration. 

They asked us to find out if BigCommerce would allow Server Integration for Sage Pay before they would activate the European Payments on our account.

Thank you for the included link, this worked fine and I can see Sofort & Giropay payment options are included.

Any further assistance you could offer me would be greatly appreciated as I am now unsure how I need to proceed?

Comment: You'll need to call up Sage Pay and get the account types activated. You could refer them to this example, or possibly get them to email me directly....

Comment: Hi - Contacted Sage Pay and this was their response - "Unfortunately it is our restriction that we can only do it on server integration so you will definitely need this." - It is looking like this may not be possible for us at this moment in time.